# Library for managing flutter rebuilds based on state changes

Tags: library, dart, flutter

This is my [new library](https://pub.dev/packages/notifier_builder) for managing flutter rebuilds based on state changes. It is very similar to [AnimatedBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) but takes a factory to create the notifier instead of an instance of the notifier. It also includes the notifier in the `builder` method. I would like to know if you can spot potential bugs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A Builder for any Listenable notifier/controller
class NotifierBuilder<T extends Listenable> extends StatefulWidget {
  ///Constructs a [NotifierBuilder]
  const NotifierBuilder({
    required this.notifier,
    required this.builder,
    super.key,
    this.child,
  });

  ///The Builder calls this when it needs a new notifier. That will only
  ///happen once
  final T Function() notifier;

  ///️ The Builder calls this when it needs to build the widget tree. You can
  ///access the notifier and its state here
  final Widget Function(
    BuildContext context,
    Widget? child,
    T notifier,
  ) builder;

  /// This is entirely optional. You can use this prebuilt Widget in the
  ///builder to improve performance, but you don't need to
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  State<NotifierBuilder> createState() => NotifierBuilderState<T>();
}

///This exposes the state of the [NotifierBuilder]. You can access the notifier
///in widget tests to verify the state
class NotifierBuilderState<T extends Listenable>
    extends State<NotifierBuilder<T>> {
  ///The notifier that was created by the [NotifierBuilder.notifier] function
  T? notifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifier ??= widget.notifier();
    notifier?.addListener(_handleChange);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    notifier ??= widget.notifier();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    notifier?.removeListener(_handleChange);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleChange() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      widget.builder(context, widget.child, notifier!);
}
```

Comment: Would anyone care to explain why there is a vote to close on this question? I don't see anything wrong.